# why curl cannot get the same response as in ie browser?

Tags: internet-explorer, curl

I have an api which run like this:

[image: result in ie browser]

so I want to get the result in my `ubuntu` machine  with `curl`, then I try this:

```
curl -v \
--header 'Accept: text/html, application/xhtml+xml, */*' \
--header 'Accept-Language: zh-CN' \
-A 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; WOW64; Trident/7.0; rv:11.0) like Gecko' \
--header 'Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate' \
--header 'Host: 10.202.15.197:20176' \
--header 'DNT: 1' \
--header 'Connection: Keep-Alive' \
http://10.202.15.197:20176?user_id=1&query_type=GEOSPLIT&address=广东省深圳市宝安&ret_splitinfo=1
```

[image: result with curl]

then strange thing happened: as you can see, **I get total different result from the ie browswer**, so I thought it must be **encoding problem**, then I try this:

```
curl -v \
--header 'Accept: text/html, application/xhtml+xml, */*' \
--header 'Accept-Language: zh-CN' \
-A 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; WOW64; Trident/7.0; rv:11.0) like Gecko' \
--header 'Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate' \
--header 'Host: 10.202.15.197:20176' \
--header 'DNT: 1' \
--header 'Connection: Keep-Alive' \
http://10.202.15.197:20176 --data-urlencode 'user_id=1&query_type=GEOSPLIT&address=广东省深圳市宝安&ret_splitinfo=1'
```

[image: I get total different result]

but no, it returns the same result, and I catch my request by `fiddler` in my windows ie browser, I get the request data:

```
GET http://10.202.15.197:20176/?user_id=1&query_type=GEOSPLIT&address=广东省深圳市宝安&ret_splitinfo=1 HTTP/1.1
Accept: text/html, application/xhtml+xml, */*
Accept-Language: zh-CN
User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; WOW64; Trident/7.0; rv:11.0) like Gecko
Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate
Host: 10.202.15.197:20176
DNT: 1
Connection: Keep-Alive
Pragma: no-cache


HTTP/1.0 200 OK
Content-Type: application/octet-stream
Connection: close
Content-Length: 222

<?xml version='1.0' encoding='GBK'?>
<addrSplitInfo>
<status>0</status><as_info prop="1" level="1">广东省</as_info>
<as_info prop="1" level="2">深圳市</as_info>
<as_info prop="3" level="18">宝安</as_info>
</addrSplitInfo>
```

Comment: Hi, hint: Fiddler uses a proxy connection.... turn off your proxy in IE's network settings.

Answer (score 0):

I do much further research in this phenomenon(see [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43647785/how-to-encode-parameter-as-gbk-instead-of-utf-8-with-curl-or-python-requests)). The reason of this is that `IE browser` will use `GBK` as default encoding meanwhile `Chrome` `Firefox` `cURL` `python-requests` just use `UTF-8` encoding.

Here is the solution to use this `API`:

with `cURL`:

```
echo "http://10.202.15.197:20176\?user_id\=1\&query_type\=GEOSPLIT\&address\=广东省深圳市宝安\&ret_splitinfo\=1" | iconv -f utf-8 -t gbk | xargs curl
```

with `python-requests`

```
payload = {"user_id": 1, "query_type": "GEOSPLIT", "address": u"广东省深圳市宝安".encode('gbk'), "ret_splitinfo": 1}
r = requests.get("http://10.202.15.197:20176", payload)
print r.text
```